# AngularJS deployment in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to run an AngularJS application using Visual Studio 2012 but IIS always opens the file tree instead of using app/index.html and when I try to navigate in the file system and run app/index.html it gives me a erro.
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: I created a new web site pointing to the directory of Angular application.

Comment: The Visual Studio 2012 solution is designed to run with IIS Express. To open it follow these steps:

1. Start Visual Studio 2012
2. Select File --> Open Website and select the AngularJSDemos folder
3. Right-click on the website project and select Use IIS Express from the menu

You should be all set.

If you don't want to use Visual Studio you can still run everything but you'd possibly need
to update the urlBase path in DemoList.html since it expects DemoPartials to be off the root
of whatever site you run.

Comment: ok That i do understand. Actually its not easy. there are lot of things to care about. angular version. your browser version, your references and so many stuffs.